# A phrase for "flip the bozo bit" for generic situations

Tags: phrase-requests

I've only recently heard of [*flip the bozo bit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bozo_bit#Dismissing_a_person_as_not_worth_listening_to) in the last six months or so, and I find it very useful to understand that aspect of human behaviour (deciding that someone's an idiot and never worth listening to again, even if they're actually making a lot of sense or are objectively correct). However, there are other very similar situations where it would be useful to have a generic phrase, such as in an online game where Player A accuses Player B of cheating, and all evidence is treated as confirming that Player B is indeed cheating, whereas a different player who has not "flipped the cheating bit" on Player B would view the evidence objectively.

Another example is in [*The Life of Brian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python%27s_Life_of_Brian), where a mob decides that Brian is the Messiah, even though he tries to convince them he isn't:

> **Brian:** I'm not the Messiah! Will you please listen? I am not the Messiah, do you understand? Honestly!
>
> **Girl:** Only the true Messiah denies His divinity.
>
> **Brian:** What? Well, what sort of chance does that give me? All right! I am the Messiah!
>
> **Followers:** He is! He is the Messiah!
>
> **Arthur:** I say you are Lord, and I should know. I've followed a few.

The mob have "flipped" Brian's "Messiah bit", and refuse to believe that he isn't. If he says he **isn't** the Messiah, that's proof that he **is** the Messiah. If he says he **is** the Messiah, that's **also** proof that he is the Messiah!

You could say things like "Keep an open mind", "Don't prejudge", etc., but they're not as strong as the original and don't get to the heart of the behaviour.

Is there a generic phrase for an auto-confirming belief/behaviour that's almost impossible to get out of that retains the strength of the original phrase?

Instead of:

> Don't **flip the bozo bit on** people.
>
> Don't _____ people.

Comment: It's worth noting that "flip the bozo bit" is *not* always used to mean "wrongly flip the bozo bit". Sometimes it's used more-or-less neutrally, to mean that someone has started ignoring someone whose errors have caused too many problems. (Cf. "cry wolf".)

Comment: A non-techie version, BTW, might be "write someone off", though that one usually requires more context to indicate what you're writing someone off *as*.

Comment: @ruakh Crying wolf is about the other person in the equation. Person A has been caught telling lies too often, so Person B is justified in being skeptical. Whereas if Person B flips the bozo bit on Person A, the fault lies in Person B, not Person A. When someone cries wolf they can redeem themselves over time, but in the original usage of "flip the bozo bit", the bit is irreversible. Writing someone off as the Messiah doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I read and understood your question. The purpose of my comment was to inform you that you are mistaken, and that "flip the bozo bit" does *not* always have the connotation you claim it does.

Comment: 'Flip the bozo bit' sounds like something that American 'Captain Neckbeard' types would say.